# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graph_tool'

Tags: python

I am new in `graph_tool`. I have installed this library using [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/v-pravin/949fc18d58a560cf85d2). Then I launched idle (Python 3) and tried to import it, but got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ihor/CS/Python_lessons/graph_tool_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from graph_tool.all import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graph_tool'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using virtualenv (or pyenv virtualenv) on a Mac, then this worked for me. You essentially need to put graph-tool into the right package directory. As brew and other installers target the incorrect folder. Here is a guide:

First, locate where graph-tool was actually installed:

```
brew info graph-tool
graph-tool: stable 2.43
Efficient network analysis for Python 3
https://graph-tool.skewed.de/
/usr/local/Cellar/graph-tool/2.43 (2,077 files, 576.8MB) *
... The rest bellow here is irrelevant...
```

Here you can see that graph-tool was installed here at **`/usr/local/Cellar/graph-tool/2.43`**

Now dig into the `/lib` folder here and locate the `site-packages` folder inside the relevant python version. Mine was:

**`/usr/local/Cellar/graph-tool/2.43/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graph_tool`**

Secondly locate where your python packages usually are. You can do this by entering the Python terminal, importing a package and then calling `__file__` on it. Example:

```
>>>> import pandas as pd
>>>> pd.__file__
'/Users/some_user/.pyenv/versions/my_project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py'
```

You can now see that your packages installed with pip are located in:
**`/Users/some_user/.pyenv/versions/my_project/lib/python3.9/site-packages`**

All you need to do is to add graph_tool to this folder through a symlink. Like so `ln-s <graph-tool-packages-directory> <vitrualenv-packages-directory>`. Example:

**`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/graph-tool/2.43/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graph_tool /Users/some_user/.pyenv/versions/my_project/lib/python3.9/site-packages`**

There might be much better ways of doing this, but this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

With Brew try the following commands:

```
brew tap brewsci/bio
brew tap brewsci/science
brew install graph-tool
```

With anaconda:

- Download anaconda ([www.anaconda.org](http://www.anaconda.org))
- Then run

```
conda config --add channels vgauthier --add channels rwest

conda install graph-tool
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for reply.
I have tried to install graph-tool using conda but got this error:

Comment: It was a bit weird for me as well, I had to look in different channels before finding the right one.  https://anaconda.org/search?q=graph-tool 
 gives you a list of available channels for your architecture (Osx-64, I guess). You can manually select a channel with -c option in conda install.  Have you tried as well the updated brew taps? Brew tap brewsci/bio and brewsci/science ? And then brew install graph-tool? Beware the latter may not work immediately with conda because conda uses his own python installation.

Comment: Remember as well to activate your conda installation, something like "source activate condaname"